# Путешествие массива из php в javascript

Tags: массивы, javascript, php

**1-й способ**

```
<?php
    $arr = new Array (...);
?>

<input id="arr" value="<?php echo json_encode($arr); ?>" hidden>

<script>
    $(function (){
      var arr = $("#arr").val(); // наш массив с "мусором"
    });
</script>
```

**2-й способ** (важен порядок кода...)

```
<?php
    $arrJS = json_encode($arr);
?>

<script>
    var arrJS = <?php echo $arrJS; ?>;  // отличный массив
</script>
```

**Есть еще способы?**

Comment: Через ajax еще можно подгружать, но это для всяких spa, которые и так сервер сотней запросов обкидывают.

Comment: @Vitalik Z, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Если используется JQuery, то можно в `data-` свойство запихнуть:

```
<?php
    $a = Array(…);
    $json = json_encode($a);
?>
<div id="some-id" data-name="<?php echo $json; ?>">…</div>
<script>
    $(function () {
        var arr = $("#some-id").data("name");
</script>
```

Но все случаи сводятся к `json_encode` на стороне PHP с последующей десериализацией в броузере.